# How to test properties and functions on a React component?

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

I've tried everything with `enzyme`, however, I can't find the correct way of testing these properties below. Keep in mind that this component is wrapped in a dummy `Provider` component so that I can pass the necessary props (i.e. `Store`) down for mounting purposes.

1) After mounting, a property is set on the instance (e.g. `this.property`)

2) An event listener has been added

3) On the event listener, `someFunction` is being called

```
class SampleComponent extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.property = 'property';
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.someFunction, true);
  }

  someFunction = () => {
    return 'hello';
  };

  render() {
    return <h1>Sample</h1>; 
  }
}

export default EvalueeExposureList;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I have updated my answer based on discussion with OP.  The component under test has a redux provider and connected component as child therefore we are opting for the usage of enzymes shallow API.

---

In regards to tracking and testing the `addEventListener` you can use the [`sinon`](http://sinonjs.org/docs/) library to create a spy, which temporarily "replaces" the `window.addEventListener`.  This grants you access to the call count as well as the arguments it was called with.

Using enzyme and mocha I created the following tests which were passing for me.  The first two test covers all your cases above and for good measure I added another on how to test the output of the `someFunction`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

// Under test.
import SampleComponent from './SampleComponent';

describe('SampleComponent', () => {
  let addEventListenerSpy;

  beforeEach(() => {
    // This replaces the window.addEventListener with our spy.
    addEventListenerSpy = sinon.spy(window, 'addEventListener');
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    // Restore the original function.
    window.addEventListener.restore();
  });

  // This asserts your No 1.
  it(`should set the property`, () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<SampleComponent />);
    wrapper.instance().componentDidMount(); // call it manually
    expect(wrapper.instance().property).equal('property');
  });

  // This asserts your No 2 and No 3.  We know that by having
  // passed the someFunction as an argument to the event listener
  // we can trust that it is called.  There is no need for us
  // to test the addEventListener API itself.
  it(`should add a "scroll" event listener`, () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<SampleComponent />);
    wrapper.instance().componentDidMount(); // call it manually
    expect(addEventListenerSpy.callCount).equal(1);
    expect(addEventListenerSpy.args[0][0]).equal('scroll');
    expect(addEventListenerSpy.args[0][1]).equal(wrapper.instance().someFunction);
    expect(addEventListenerSpy.args[0][2]).true;
  });

  it(`should return the expected output for the someFunction`, () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<SampleComponent />);
    expect(wrapper.instance().someFunction()).equal('hello');
  });
});
```

It may be worth noting that I run my tests on node, but I have a `jsdom` setup in my `mocha` configuration, which is probably the candidate responsible for creating the `window.addEventListener` in for use in my test environment. Are you running your tests via the browser or node? If node you may need to do something similar to me.

Comment: Thank you, much, for this detailed answer. However, I continue to get `undefined` for the class properties. I have a few sitting inside of the constructor as shown above and some are set on `componentDidMount`, yet none are returning any values: `console.log(wrapper.instance().someProperty)`

Comment: Any chance you could update your question with an example test?

Comment: I see, I have my component inside of a mocked provider, so the `instance` method is returning the parent instead of the desired instance. This is unfortunate, as I cannot get the instance of the `child` component with the `instance` method.

Comment: You should export both your wrapped component and the component without the wrapping so that you can test it in isolation.

Comment: You don't need a Provider with a store to pass props, you can simply pass the props via the test. e.g. `mount(<MyComponent propOne="foo" />)`

Comment: The only issue is that I continue getting this error: `Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Component)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Component)".` as it's asking in order for it to be used in the connect, hence why I decided to wrap it in a `Provider` component

Comment: Oh, cool you are using redux connect, I will update my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114672/discussion-between-ctrlplusb-and-detuned).